# Query length of a vector in MathNet.Numerics namespace

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

Is there any way to find the dimensions of a vector (or even matrix) for a Vector data structure in the MathNet.Numerics namespace. Something along the lines of

```
int dimension = 3;
Vector<int> x = Vector<int>.Build.Dense(dimension);
int lengthOfX = x.Length();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the respective property is a little bit counterintuitive, but it's there: `Vector<T>.Count`:

> Gets the length or number of dimensions of this vector.

See the [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Vector%601.htm).

For a `Matrix<T>` the properties are `ColumnCount` and `RowCount` — [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Matrix%601.htm).